# How do I create an ami for openSUSE in Amazon ec2?

Tags: opensuse, amazon-ec2

I need to scale some services from local servers to Amazon ec2. The current production-environment is based on the latest openSUSE. In order to keep things simple, I want to run the instances in ec2 in the same environment.

However, I'm unable to find any public SUSE ami's or even howto's on this subject. I've seen a few similar questions in different forums, without any resolutions.

So actually, I have two questions.

1) Is this at all doable?
  2) If, so, is there any documentation / howto's available somewhere?

Jarle

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question. Yes, it can be done - I was just searhing in the wrong region. ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com has both 32 and 64 bits public ami's. This [thread](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/thread.jspa?threadID=41888&tstart=90#177093) gives some advices about openSUSE and ec2.